# How to specify the columns in a MultiMap query instead of using * (asterisk)

Tags: dapper

Sometimes I don't want to fill my entities entirely (some properties are not always necessary), but, how can I specify the table columns in a MultiMap query?

Just an example:

Table Costumer
ID (PK)
Name
Address
CityID (FK to Table City, column ID)
Email

Table City
ID (PK)
Name
State

I need to use a query like this:

```
    SELECT Costumer.ID, Costumer.Name, Costumer.Email, City.ID AS CityID, City.Name AS CityName
    FROM Costumer INNER JOIN City ON Costumer.CityID = City.ID
```

My question is: how can I specify the join columns without having name conflict and having dapper to identify the mapping between the columns and the entity's properties?

Comment: What are the primary key / identity columns? Where does each join end?

Comment: Just added more detail to the question.

Comment: and what object model do you want to read it into? A separate "Customer" / "City" type? or a "Customer" record with a "CiteID" and "CityName" member? what do you want the shape to be in the .NET code?

Comment: I need to get a Customer object that has a City class instance as property with CityID and CityName values filled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the clarifications in the comments, it *should* work something like:

```
var custs = conn.Query<Customer,City,Customer>(sql,
       (cust,city) => { cust.City = city; return cust; },
       splitOn: "ID,CityID").ToList();
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get home.